# make sub graph from boost graph using particular parent

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

[image]

I want sub graph like C, F, H and D, G using boost library.
I have all the parents like in above example C and D.

Comment: What code do you have. Also, this looks like a tree. Why not use a tree? Finally, why do you consistenly not mention B or B-E?

Comment: Just for graphical represent I draw like that, yes I also want to take out B-E.Here is the adjacency list 
boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, GraphItem>.

Comment: Edited the image to reflect the graph model as you commented. This code http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ebc84d38071e75f or this http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c30f1c72c752099d would generate this graph. It's rendered using dot (e.g. http://www.webgraphviz.com/)

Comment: Please describe what makes "D,G" an interesting sub graph, as opposed to e.g. "B,D,G", or even "B,D,G,E".

Answer (score 3):

I struggled to make sense of the description. I think I've figured it out. Please consider specifying the requirements instead of merely giving one incomplete example next time.

### Starting From The Root

First I thought that you meant to find the root (zero in-edges) and treat each child node as a subgraph.

However, this results in:

```
// roots are nodes with a zero in-degree (no parents)
Vertices roots;
boost::remove_copy_if(vertices(g), back_inserter(roots), [&](Vertex v) { return boost::size(in_edges(v, g)); });

std::vector<Graph> subs;
for (Vertex root : roots) {
    for (Vertex subroot : boost::make_iterator_range(adjacent_vertices(root, g))) {

        std::set<Vertex> include;
        std::vector<boost::default_color_type> colors(n);

        boost::depth_first_visit(g, subroot, 
                boost::make_dfs_visitor(
                        boost::write_property(
                            boost::identity_property_map{},
                            inserter(include, include.end()),
                            boost::on_discover_vertex())
                    ),
                colors.data());

        std::cout << "Root " << g[root].name << ": Subtree rooted at " << g[subroot].name << " includes " << include.size() << " nodes\n";

        Filtered fg(g, boost::keep_all{}, [&](Vertex v) { return include.count(v); });
        print_graph(fg, names);
    }
}
```

Printing **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8992e0bf10f557bf)</kbd>**

```
Root A: Subtree rooted at B includes 4 nodes
B --> D E 
D --> G 
E --> 
G --> 
Root A: Subtree rooted at C includes 3 nodes
C --> F 
F --> H 
H -->
```

Indeed, `D` is obviously not a child of `A` so would not count.

Back to the drawing board.

### Starting From The Leafs

All sub-trees containing single-degree children or leaf nodes?

This *would* indeed seem to describe the "linear" subgraphs given as an example. Obviously, the "linear" (vertical) layout is an arbitrary layout choice. All three of the representations below are exactly equivalent to the question graph:

[image]

Looking at this the opposite way suddenly makes a lot more sense: you may want to list all the linear dependencies starting from each *leaf* node, until you reach a node that also participates in another branch.

This naturally involves doing a topological search and listing each branch in the DAG from the leaf-node back:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4561e48464e27a2b)</kbd>**

```
Vertices reverse_topological;
boost::topological_sort(g, back_inserter(reverse_topological));

bool in_path = true;
for (auto v : reverse_topological) {
    if (0 == out_degree(v, g)) { // is leaf?
        in_path = true;
        std::cout << "\nLeaf:";
    }

    in_path &= (1 == in_degree(v, g));

    if (in_path)
        std::cout << " " << names[v];
    else
        std::cout << " [" << names[v] << "]";
}
```

Prints:

```
Leaf: G D
Leaf: E B
Leaf: H F C [A]
```

### Minor Variation:

You can indicate that `B` doubles in two paths, depending on your requirements:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08817b3595b0861e)</kbd>**

```
Vertices reverse_topological;
boost::topological_sort(g, back_inserter(reverse_topological));

bool in_path = true;
for (auto v : reverse_topological) {
    switch (out_degree(v, g)) {
        case 0:
            // start a new path
            in_path = true;
            std::cout << "\nLeaf:";
            break;
        case 1: 
            break; // still single-degree
        default: in_path = false;
    }

    if (in_path)
        std::cout << " " << names[v];
    else
        std::cout << " [" << names[v] << "]";
}
```

Prints

```
Leaf: G D
Leaf: E [B]
Leaf: H F C [A]
```

### Full Listings

To preserve against bitrot:

- Starting from the root (first assumption)

  ```
  #include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

  struct GraphItem {
      std::string name;
  };

  using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, GraphItem>;
  using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
  using Vertices = std::vector<Vertex>;

  #include <boost/graph/filtered_graph.hpp>
  #include <boost/function.hpp>
  using Filtered = boost::filtered_graph<Graph, boost::keep_all, boost::function<bool(Vertex)>>;

  #include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
  #include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
  #include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
  #include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>

  int main() {

      Graph g;
      auto names = get(&GraphItem::name, g);

      enum {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,n};
      Vertices vs {
          add_vertex({"A"}, g),
          add_vertex({"B"}, g),
          add_vertex({"C"}, g),
          add_vertex({"D"}, g),
          add_vertex({"E"}, g),
          add_vertex({"F"}, g),
          add_vertex({"G"}, g),
          add_vertex({"H"}, g),
      };

      assert(num_vertices(g) == n); 
      add_edge(vs[A], vs[B], g);
      add_edge(vs[A], vs[C], g);

      add_edge(vs[B], vs[D], g);
      add_edge(vs[B], vs[E], g);

      add_edge(vs[D], vs[G], g);

      add_edge(vs[C], vs[F], g);
      add_edge(vs[F], vs[H], g);

      // write_graphviz(std::cout, g, make_label_writer(names));

      // roots are nodes with a zero in-degree (no parents)
      Vertices roots;
      boost::remove_copy_if(vertices(g), back_inserter(roots), [&](Vertex v) { return boost::size(in_edges(v, g)); });

      std::vector<Graph> subs;
      for (Vertex root : roots) {
          for (Vertex subroot : boost::make_iterator_range(adjacent_vertices(root, g))) {

              std::set<Vertex> include;
              std::vector<boost::default_color_type> colors(n);

              boost::depth_first_visit(g, subroot, 
                      boost::make_dfs_visitor(
                              boost::write_property(
                                  boost::identity_property_map{},
                                  inserter(include, include.end()),
                                  boost::on_discover_vertex())
                          ),
                      colors.data());

              std::cout << "Root " << g[root].name << ": Subtree rooted at " << g[subroot].name << " includes " << include.size() << " nodes\n";

              Filtered fg(g, boost::keep_all{}, [&](Vertex v) { return include.count(v); });
              print_graph(fg, names);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Starting from the leaves (second assumption, topological-sort)

  ```
  #include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

  struct GraphItem {
      std::string name;
  };

  using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, GraphItem>;
  using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
  using Vertices = std::vector<Vertex>;

  #include <boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp>
  #include <iostream>

  int main() {

      Graph g;
      auto names = get(&GraphItem::name, g);

      {
          enum {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,n};
          Vertices vs {
              add_vertex({"A"}, g),
              add_vertex({"B"}, g),
              add_vertex({"C"}, g),
              add_vertex({"D"}, g),
              add_vertex({"E"}, g),
              add_vertex({"F"}, g),
              add_vertex({"G"}, g),
              add_vertex({"H"}, g),
          };

          assert(num_vertices(g) == n); 
          add_edge(vs[A], vs[B], g);
          add_edge(vs[A], vs[C], g);

          add_edge(vs[B], vs[D], g);
          add_edge(vs[B], vs[E], g);

          add_edge(vs[D], vs[G], g);

          add_edge(vs[C], vs[F], g);
          add_edge(vs[F], vs[H], g);
      }

      Vertices reverse_topological;
      boost::topological_sort(g, back_inserter(reverse_topological));

      bool in_path = true;
      for (auto v : reverse_topological) {
          if (0 == out_degree(v, g)) { // is leaf?
              in_path = true;
              std::cout << "\nLeaf:";
          }

          in_path &= (1 == in_degree(v, g));

          if (in_path)
              std::cout << " " << names[v];
          else
              std::cout << " [" << names[v] << "]";
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Simplified version of the topological-sort approach that doesn't require the BidirectionalGraph concept anymore: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f6664ba4d23cc65

Comment: Well I am really novice to boost but what I want is I have that directedS graph(I don't want to change to any other graph type) and If I want to get a subgraph from main graph how should I get it.
for example, 
1. If I pass B(root) I should get subgraph like (B,D,E,G)
2. If I pass C as root I should get subgraph like (C,F,H).

To pass which root should be my(user)'s choice.
Hope its clear for you :).